# React doesn't re-render after State change on button click in ReactJS (preact)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, preact

I have the following code which is working except that it doesn't re-render the page after pressing a button.

I have two different buttons being displayed depending on wether a user is part of a room or not.  If a user is part of a room they can click on LEAVE which will execute an API call. I would then like the component to reload and for the button to display JOIN (since they are no longer part of that room).

```
import JoinedRooms from '../../components/matrix_joined_rooms';
import JoinRoom from '../../components/matrix_function_join_room';
import LeaveRoom from '../../components/matrix_function_leave_room';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'preact/hooks';

const JoinLeaveButton = ({ name, roomId }) => {
  const joinedRooms = JoinedRooms();
  const [x, setX] = useState(5);

  useEffect(() => console.log("re-render because x changed:", x), [x])

  const handleXClick = (number) => {
    setX(number)
  }

  if (joinedRooms.includes(name)) {
    return <button name={roomId} onClick={() => {
      LeaveRoom(roomId);
      handleXClick(10);
    }
    }>LEAVE</button>
  } else {
    return <button name={roomId} onClick={() => {
      JoinRoom(roomId);
      handleXClick(20);
    }
    }>JOIN</button>
  }
}

export default JoinLeaveButton;
```

my JoinRoom and LeaveRoom components are a simple API call which look like this:

```
const JoinRoom = (roomId) => {
  fetch(`https://example.com/_matrix/client/r0/rooms/${roomId}/join`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("mx_access_token")}`
    }
  });
}

export default JoinRoom;
```

The funcionality of the button itself works, the problem is that I have to manually reload the page for it to be displayed correctly.

I have put a dummy state in place which is executed whenever you press the button and it also logs to the console properly.
I was under the impression, that changing a state should re-render a component in React (or in this case preact).

Thanks!

Comment: It's because `joinedRooms` isn't being updated.

Comment: I see you are trying to make (async) API calls outside of useEffect, as well as not listening for when it changes in your UseEffect - you are listening for changes to [x]

Comment: Both `JoinRoom` and `LeaveRoom` are asyncronous operations therefore you have to await for them to complete before triggering the page reload with `handleXClick`.

Comment: @secan - that's not a helpful comment. The OP was obviously trying to hack something into place with the x state.

Comment: Hi @Adam, you are probably right but I tend to limit as much as possible my assumptions when reading someone else's code. My take on the matter is that, unless it is explicitly declared otherwise, OPs have a reason for doing things the way they do. Anyway, thank you very much for your feedback; I'll try to adjust my future comments so that they'll be more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essense: **you need to store the state of the joined rooms somewhere and have that state updated everytime a user joins or leaves a room**.

I've gone way overboard here, but a custom hook like this makes a lot of sense:

```js
// api calls
const fetchRooms = async userid => { ... }
const joinRoom = async (userId,roomId) => { ... }
const leaveRoom = async (userId,roomId) => { ... }

// custom hook
const useRooms = (userId) => {
   const [fetching,setFetching] = useState(true);
   const [error,setError] = useState(false);

   // joinedRooms state is an empty array when this hook is first used
   // it will be updated later using the useEffect hook
   // or via the join or leave functions below
   const [joinedRooms,setJoinedRooms] = useState([]);

   // when the component that uses this hook is mounted
   // or the user id changes, update the state
   useEffect(() => {
       let canceled;

       setFetching(true);
       (async() => {
          try {
             const rooms = await fetchRooms(userId);
             canceled || setJoinedRooms(rooms);
          } catch(err) {
             canceled || setError(error);
          } finally {
             canceled || setFetching(false);
          }
       })();
       return () => canceled = true;
   },[userId]);

   const leave = async roomId => {
     try {
        await leaveRoom(userId,roomId)
        // alternatively you could fetch all the user rooms again here
        setJoinedRooms(joined => joined.filter(r => r !== roomId));
     } catch(err) {
       // couldn't leave the room - what do you want to do with the state?
     }
   }

   const join = async roomId => {
     try {
        await joinRoom(userId,roomId);
        // alternatively you could fetch all the user rooms again here
        setJoinedRooms(joined => [...joined,roomId]);
     } catch(err) {
       // couldn't join the room - what do you want to do with the state?
     }
   }

   return {
      fetching,
      error,
      joinedRooms,
      leave,
      join
   }


}
```

In a component you'd use it something like this:

```js
const Rooms = (userId,listOfAllYourRoomIds) => {
   const { joinedRooms, fetching, error, join, leave } = useRooms(userId);

   // the `join` and `leave` functions are what you'll call 
   // when a user wants to join or leave a room, the joinedRooms prop will get
   // updated according, and everything will "just work"

   return listOfAllYourRoomIds.map(roomId => <SomeRoomComponent roomId={roomId}/>)
   
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! have to admit I don't completely understand it, yet but I will work through it!